# Get a specific value from an array in swift ios

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a testModel object. How can I get an array containing only the id field from testModel to store in nameID

Below is my code

```
struct Model {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```

ViewController

```
  let nameID = [Int]()

  let testModel = [Model(id: 1, name: ""), Model(id: 2, name: ""), Model(id: 3, name: "")]

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

   let people = testModel.map { item in
          print(item.id)
         self.nameID = item.id
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never have side effects (mutating state) inside the closure of a `map`. instead, you simply need to return `item.id` and then assign `people` to `hairstyleID`.

```
let ids = testModel.map { item in item.id }
self.hairstyleID = ids
```

You can also simplify the map using `KeyPath`s `testModel.map(\.id)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
hairstyleID = testModel.map { $0.id }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get an array containing only the id field from testModel to store in nameID is to use map:

```
let nameID:[Int] = []
let testModel = [Model(id: 1, name: ""), Model(id: 2, name: ""), Model(id: 3, name: "")]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    nameID = testModel.map{ $0.id }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get all id's and a simple filter example to get some model from the list:

```
struct Model {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

func workWithModel() {
    let modelList = [Model(id: 1, name: "Home"), Model(id: 2, name: "Work"), Model(id: 3, name: "Other place")]
    // Get all id's
    let nameIDs = modelList.map { $0.id }
        
    print("Name IDs: \(nameIDs)")
        
    // Filter some model
    guard let whereAreYou = modelList.first(where: {
        $0.name == "Work" || $0.name.contains("w")
    }) else { return }
        
    print("Just now you are in: \(whereAreYou)")
}
```

The output is:

```
Name IDs: [1, 2, 3]
Just now you are in: Model(id: 2, name: "Work")
```

Comment: What has this got to do with the question?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I don't understand what you mean, if it's about the filter, then I'm showing how to get only the IDs using map and how to filter in case he needs it and doesn't happen to know it, he doesn't have to ask again.

Comment: I actually missed that you had answered the question among the other stuff. Try to keep your answers more focused. Anyway, this is a duplicate answer.

Comment: I'll keep it in mind.